# Get the default left,top,width,height values (position and size) for a window per process, or global Windows values

Tags: c#, windows, height, width, position

If I move and resize the Notepad window to, let's say: Left:100, Top:100, Width: 1000, Height: 800, the next time I open Notepad, the window will automatically open at that location and size. The same with Firefox, etc.

Is there a way (Windows API function, etc.) to get these default values (left, top, width, height) of the window for a specific process (if I have a window handle and/or a process name/id)?

If it's not possible per process, is there a function to get the default left,top,width,height of any window that is opened on Windows?

I'm using C# and .Net Framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How each application stores its defaults is based on per-application. Usually it's in the registry.